# Visual Studio: How to easily convert a method and its callers to async

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asynchronous, task

In VS2019, is it possible to change a method's signature to return a `Task` or `Task<T>` and make all upstream callers async as well in a cascading manner?

Comment: You mean, in an automated way, like a built-in refactoring?

Comment: I do not think so, not in a cascading manner.

Comment: The AsyncFixer (http://www.asyncfixer.com/) is an extension for Visual Studio that will highlight places that can or should be async. When you mark your method as such, it will light up the next level up to change. The problem is that just changing the signature is often not enough, one should not depend on sync methods when async are available. These will often also be highlighted by the AsyncFixer. It's the closest to it.

Comment: I searched around for quite a while, couldn't find anything. I finally wrote a small javascript tool that uses regexes to parse a copy/pasted declaration from VS, makes the `Task<val>` return type, adds `Async` postfix to the method name, and adds the `CancellationToken` parameter to the end of the variable declaration list. Even still, it's going to take hundreds of manhours to convert our codebase. I would pay a lot of money if someone made a VS plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In VS2019, is it possible to change a method's signature to return a Task or Task...

Short answer is No.

For one can *refactor* the name of the method and if you choose the intellisense option to rename, the name will be changed for the callers, but it will not handle any of the async needs you are wanting. In other words the refactoring is not async aware.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be asynchronous, a method needs to be marked as async and to return either a Task or a Task. We could change it like this:

```
//previously:
public int Something()
{
    int something = ...;
    return something;
}

//now
public async Task<int> Something()
{
    int something = ...;
    return await Task.FromResult(something);
}
```

Mind you, this does not make it inherently asynchronous, it just takes care of the signature of it.